# Problem on update manager

Tags: linux, upgrade

I am using [OS4](http://www.os4online.com/).

When I installed the OS and went to update manager it told me:

> Requires installation of untrusted packages : mountall

Can you tell me what I should do?

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the steps outlined in this AskUbuntu question and answer thread titled: [Requires installation of untrusted packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages).

I would try the steps outlined in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/185366/17531) specifically:

```
$ sudo apt-get clean
$ cd /var/lib/apt
$ sudo mv lists lists.old
$ sudo mkdir -p lists/partial
$ sudo apt-get clean 
$ sudo apt-get update
```

These steps will rebuild your `apt` cache which sounds like it's gotten corrupt.